# Intel intrinsic data type inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, vectorization, unions, intrinsics

I want to know how to properly use intel intrinsic data type in my program,
the way I am currently using involve the use of `_mm256_loadu_ps` and `_mm256_storeu_ps` for loading and storing results. But the code runs slower than simple code and after checking, I found that 80% of the time is consumed in loading and storing.

so I m thinking of doing something like this to avoid loading and storing

```
union _64bytes {
    float m[4][4] = {0};
    __m256 regs[2];
};

struct st {
  _64bytes mat44;
 float f ; int i;
// ...... and other things
};
```

Is this method right ?  or should I stick to the same loading and storing.
and Also there will be thousands of instances of struct st in my program, probably a vector of big size.

Now I have changed the code to this to avoid any temporaries.

```
_mm_storeu_ps(&t.mat[0][0], _mm_mul_ps(_mm_add_ps(_mm_div_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(&t.mat[0][0]), _mm_set1_ps(t.mat[0][3])), _ones), _scl));
_mm_storeu_ps(&t.mat[1][0], _mm_mul_ps(_mm_add_ps(_mm_div_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(&t.mat[1][0]), _mm_set1_ps(t.mat[1][3])), _ones), _scl));
_mm_storeu_ps(&t.mat[2][0], _mm_mul_ps(_mm_add_ps(_mm_div_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(&t.mat[2][0]), _mm_set1_ps(t.mat[2][3])), _ones), _scl));
```

Comment: Quick answer: It's not right. And yes, you should stick to the loading and storing methods provided by the api.

Comment: > * found that 80% of the time is consumed in loading and storing* You need to show that portion of code so that people can maybe understand why it is slow and help you

Comment: Unions still have to compile to asm; it doesn't generally help to write vector-element access this way; the actual work is still needed and the resulting asm is usually similar at best, or could be worse if it compiles in a way that creates store-forwarding stalls.  Make sure you compile with full optimization, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, for now, I will stick to the non-vectorized way and will found some other area of the program that can benefit from vectorization significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs slowly because you most likely do too little operations between calls to `_mm256_loadu_ps` and `_mm256_storeu_ps` functions.
You should perform as many operations as possible between calls to these functions, e.g.

```
xmm1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr);
xmm2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr2);
xmm1 = _mm256_add_ps(xmm1,xmm2);
xmm1 = _mm256_sub_ps(xmm1,xmm2);
xmm1 = ...;
_mm256_storeu_ps(result_ptr,xmm1);
```

and not

```
xmm1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr);
xmm2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr2);
xmm1 = _mm256_add_ps(xmm1,xmm2);
_mm256_storeu_ps(result_ptr,xmm1);

xmm1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr);
xmm2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(some_ptr3);
xmm1 = _mm256_sub_ps(xmm1,xmm2);
_mm256_storeu_ps(result_ptr,xmm1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also think that's the case .  i was calling store and load funtion too frequently.